# No onto map between group algebras $FS_5$ onto $M_6(F)$.

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups, algebras, group-rings, ring-homomorphism

> I have to prove that there does not exist a surjective group algebra homomorphism from $FS_5$(the group algebra of the symmetric grpoup, $S_5$, over the field $F$) to $M_6(F)$, where $F$ is the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $M_6(F)$ denotes the matrix algebra of $6\times 6$ matrices over the field $F$.

I have no idea how to prove it exactly. I am thinking which matrix doesn’t comes in range if particular map is defined.  The dimension of domain algebra also bigger one. I already have link of the problem [Artin-Wedderburn decomposition of $\mathbb{F}_2[S_5]/J$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206847/artin-wedderburn-decomposition-of-mathbbf-2s-5-j). But I do not know representation theory. Please give me a suggestion that does not use representation theory.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you recall what $FS_5$ is?

Comment: I think the group algebra on the symmetric group $S_5$ over the field $F$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net   Yes i think i already told about group algebra...

Comment: If there was such a map, there would have to be an irreducible six-dimensional representation of $S_5$ over $F$. Can you determine the dimensions of the irreducible representations?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am not having knowledge of Representation theory...

Comment: I want to solve it without using representation theory

Comment: You are most welcome if you give answer by using representation theory but please give details also ....thanks

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206847/artin-wedderburn-decomposition-of-mathbbf-2s-5-j I already have link to that

Comment: The answer by Stephen there settles your problem. @neelkanth

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I edit the question.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes sir but i already told i want to prove this by simple concept of group and ring theory.

Comment: @Saad it’s group ring question also ??